# Parsing HTML in R using XML and RCurl

Tags: html, xml, r, macos, rcurl

I am trying to parse the content of a website but I receive an error message. I don't know how to deal with the error:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
html <- getURL("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/8947/000119312506125763/0001193125-06-125763.txt")
doc <- htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
```

This is the error message I get:

Error: XML content does not seem to be XML, nor to identify a file name

I am working on a Mac:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8          rJava_0.9-4       R.utils_1.26.2    R.oo_1.13.9       R.methodsS3_1.4.4 gsubfn_0.6-5      proto_0.3-10      RCurl_1.95-4.1   
[9] bitops_1.0-6      splus2R_1.2-0     stringr_0.6.2     foreign_0.8-54    XML_3.95-0.2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tcltk_3.0.1 tools_3.0.1
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Works on 
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need curl to get the file, the built in tools can read test from urls (eg. `scan` or `read.table`).

The reason you're getting this error is the file isn't valid XML or HTML. Strip out all the lines before the `<HTML>` tag and you should be good to go.

```
sec <- scan(file = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/8947/000119312506125763/0001193125-06-125763.txt", what = "character", sep ="\n",  allowEscapes = TRUE)
sec <- sec[56:length(sec)]
secHTML <- htmlParse(sec)
```

There are other, less ugly ways to get the file, but once you strip the 'text' preamble XML should be able to parse it.

Alternately I think there's a parameter to `htmlParse` which allows you to specify a number of lines to skip.

Comment: Thanks. I modified you're solution slightly:                        `sec <- scan(file = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/8947/000119312506125763/0001193125-06-125763.txt", what = "character", sep ="\n",  allowEscapes = TRUE)
sec <- sec[grep("<HTML>", sec)[1]:length(sec)]
secHTML <- htmlParse(sec)`

Comment: Try not to grep for HTML tags. This one is pretty innocuous, but it can get you into weird spots of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

```
> txt <- readLines(url("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/8947/000119312506125763/0001193125-06-125763.txt"))
> head(txt)
[1] "-----BEGIN PRIVACY-ENHANCED MESSAGE-----"                         
[2] "Proc-Type: 2001,MIC-CLEAR"                                        
[3] "Originator-Name: webmaster@www.sec.gov"                           
[4] "Originator-Key-Asymmetric:"                                       
[5] " MFgwCgYEVQgBAQICAf8DSgAwRwJAW2sNKK9AVtBzYZmr6aGjlWyK3XmZv3dTINen"
[6] " TWSM7vrzLADbmYQaionwg5sDW3P6oaM5D3tdezXMm7z1T+B+twIDAQAB"    

> length(txt)
[1] 5517
```

Answer (score 1):

The filings stored on the www.sec.gov website are a mixture of different types of files. Some are plain text, some are jpg, some are gif, some are pdf, some are XML, some are XBRL, and some are html, and others. The example file you are using is the "RAW Dissemination" file type, that is actually a combination of any, or all of the other types.

The file name "0001193125-06-125763.txt" is a concatenation of the "Accession Number" and the txt extension. This RAW Dissemination file is made up of Header Data, and a series of "<DOCUMENT> ....</DOCUMENT>" Tag sets. What comes between the start and end DOCUMENT Tag is the various "files" within the "filing".

The each of the different files within a filing should be treated separately. The PDFS, JPG, GIF file types are UUEncoded, and should be UUdecoded. Others like TXT, HTML, XML, XBRL should be treated as plain text, and if needed, parsed as the appropriate type.

The Header Data tags information about the companies, people, filers, filer agents, etc who have submitted the filing.